# How it write at HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
  <a href="#{root_path}">
    <img src="tree.png" id="icon">
    City Park
  </a>
</div>
```

I don't understand how it write at HAML

Comment: This is basic knowledge. Go read a tutorial! Here http://haml.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```html
.navbar-brand
  %a{:href => "#{root_path}"}
    %img#icon{:src => "tree.png"}
    City Park
```

**Update 2019**

```
.navbar-brand
  %a{href: root_path}
    %img#icon{src: "tree.png"}
    City Park
```

Comment: Just wanted to add for anyone who has installed and/or uses Atom, there is a handy HTML-2-HAML extension (https://github.com/jaunkst/atom-html2haml). There is also one for Sublime (https://github.com/pachkovsky/sublime-html-to-haml). These do the same as the app to which Thiago's linked in his comment but it's right in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navbar-brand
  = link_to ("#{'City Park'} #{image_tag 'tree.png', :id => 'icon'}").html_safe, root_path
```

Short and simple :-)